# How to Override jquery widget method in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, jquery, widget, mixins

I'm trying to override `Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar.js` `_initContent` method. I need to delete two events from it and create my own events instead. Is it possible without copying the full method from the original `sidebar.js`? I created mixin and I can call the original method by `this._super()` but I don't know how I can access events array in my mixin. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't do that without copying the code from parent. If you call this._super() then ofz you will execute whole logic of parent method.
Another thing is the _initContent is marked as @private and therefore should be not extended. The best way here will be to implement your own logic either with usage of mixin or with require-config.js map override.